# Como aplicar isdigit en una lista de caracteres de una data (Python) para obtener int y float?

Tags: python, float

Tengo una lista en python, quiero convertir las cadenas de valores que tienen números en int o float para ello utilizo el `isdigit`. Cree una función, pero esta solo es aplicada a la primera columna, alguien podría verificar el código por favor, quiero que mi función pueda aplicarse a toda mi data.

Aqui les dejo parte de mi codigo:

```
list = [['Year','Fruta','Color','Codigo','Peso'],
        ['2010','manzana','ROJA','01','0.290'],
        ['2010','naranja','NARANJA','05','0.590']]

def str2intfloat(data):
    indice = 0
    for ligne in data[1:]:
        if isinstance(ligne[indice],str) and ligne[indice].isdigit():
            ligne[indice] = int(ligne[indice])
            indice+=1
    return data
nuevos_datos=str2intfloat(list)

print(nuevos_datos[1])
```

**Salida:**

```
[2010, 'manzana', 'ROJA', '01', '0.290']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`str.isdigit` retorna True solo si todos los caracteres son dígitos, no te vale para lo que quieres, al menos no directamente:

> ```
> >>> "0.25".isdigit()
> False
>
> >>> "-25".isdigit()
> False get.
> >>> "inf".isdigit() # inf, -inf y nan son también floats válidos
> False
> ```

Podrías iterar y comprobar que cada carácter sea `+`, `-`, `.` (además de comprobar que no aparezcan duplicados y en la posición correcta) o un dígito, o usar expresiones regulares.

No obstante, el manejo de excepciones es más simple, directo (muchas veces considerablemente más eficiente) y no tiene nada de malo si se usa correctamente y para manejar excepciones concretas que sabemos cómo, cuándo y porqué tendrán lugar, es una práctica común y perfectamente aceptable en Python. get.

```
lista = [['Year','Frua','Color','Codigo','Peso'],
         ['2010','manzana','ROJA','01','0.290'],
         ['2010','naranja','NARANJA','05','0.590']]

def str2num(data):
    for item in data:
        try:
            yield int(item)
        except ValueError:
            try:
                yield float(item)
            except ValueError:
                yield item
        
            
nuevos_datos = list(str2num(lista[1]))
print(nuevos_datos)
```

> [2010, 'manzana', 'ROJA', 1, 0.29]

Si quieres convertir todas las sublistas, puedes hacer:

```
nuevos_datos = [list(str2num(sublista)) for sublista in lista]
```

o desde un enfoque funcional:

```
nuevos_datos = list(map(list, map(str2num, lista)))
```

He usado un generador en vez de retornar una lista directamente porque es más versátil, pero la idea sería la misma:

```
def str2num(data: list) -> list:
    new_data = []
    for item in data:
        try:
            new_data.append(int(item))
        except ValueError:
            try:
                new_data.append(float(item))
            except ValueError:
                new_data.append(item)
    return new_data
```

De nuevo, para aplicar a todas las sublistas:

```
nuevos_datos = [str2num(sublista) for sublista in lista]
```

o:

```
nuevos_datos = list(map(str2num, lista))
```

Puedes hacerlo todo en la función para que convierta cada item de las sublistas directamente, pero pierde su flexibilidad y la posibilidad de poder ser reutilizada con cualquier iterable:

```
def str2num(data):
    new_data = []
    for row in data:
        new_row = []
        for item in row:
            try:
                new_row.append(int(item))
            except ValueError:
                try:
                    new_row.append(float(item))
                except ValueError:
                    new_row.append(item)
        new_data.append(new_row)
    return new_data
```

No uses `list` como nombre para una variable nunca, `list` es un builtin (que además identifica y permite construir objetos `list` (lista)). No debes usar nunca dichos nombres a no ser que tengas una buena razón y sea adrede con la intención de solapar un builtin, en cuyo caso documéntalo siempre.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la acotacion sobre `list` y lista.
He probado su codigo (el primero) y aunque funciona para todas las lineas por separado, no lo hace con la data completa, es decir 

`[['Year', 'Fruta', 'Color', 'Codigo', 'Peso'], ['2010', 'manzana', 'ROJA', '01', '0.290'], ['2010', 'naranja', 'NARANJA', '05', '0.590']]`

Comment: Es porque solo está mandando una sublista a la función, `list(str2num(lista[1]))`. Para procesar toda la data tendrías que hacer un `for sublista in lista:` y en la siguiente línea mandar a llamar `nuevos_datos = list(str2num(sublista))`

Comment: @ladypolo19 he completado la respuesta con lo que bien comenta aeportugal, simplemente tienes que aplicar la función a cada sublista iterando sobre la lista de listas. Mira la respuesta a ver si te queda más claro.

Comment: Muchas gracias @FJSevilla y @aeportugal, soy nueva en python, de ahi ese detalle grave con lo de `list`, muchas gracias! 
Si quedo claro con lo de `for sublista in lista`

Comment: Hola @ladypolo19 tampoco es que sea un erro garrafal, estrictamente hablando no es un error ya que no son palabras reservadas, por eso el intérprete no se queja. Python te permite hacer muchas cosas incluso solapar los builtins con tus propias funciones o variables. El problema es que no podrás usar más list para generar una lista y además el código puede ser confuso para otros usuarios. Por convención, si no hay más remedio se usa un guion bajo final (list_).

Comment: Es totalmente normal que si empiezas no conozcas todas las funciones builtin o módulos de la stdlib (también es aconsejable evitar usar los mismos nombres de éstos para no confundir y evitar errores, especialmente nunca nombrar módulos propios con nombres de módulos de la stdlib o de terceros que podamos llegar a usar). Puedes ver un listado completo de las funciones builtin en la documentación: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html. Saludos y, por cierto, bienvenida a [es.so]  @ladypolo19.